# How to pass additional (radio-buttons) parameters through rails form created with form_for?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, form-for

I have a form_for helper that creates an object for my `Image` model. It looks like this:

```
<%= form_for :image, url: images_path do |f| %> 

  <p>
    <%= f.file_field :file %> 
  </p> 

  <p>
    <input type="radio" name="index" value="1">1 
    <input type="radio" name="index" value="2">2
    <input type="radio" name="index" value="3">3
  </p>

  <p><%= f.submit "submit" %></p> 
<% end %>
```

After observing the params hash, the :file is getting passed as expected. I need the value in the radio buttons to be passed in this hash as well, or at the very least, I need to know what this value is in the `create` function of the Image controller. How can I pass this value through the params hash (or through some other way)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the `name` attribute of the radio buttons to be like this `image[index]`.

A better way (IMO) is to use instance variables to store such value, as it will allow you to write code like `f.radio_button :index`.

For example

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessor :index
   # Uncomment if you're using Rails < 4, otherwise whitelist the attr in the controller
   #attr_accessible :index 
end
```

On the side, consider using form helpers like [`radio_button_tag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-radio_button_tag), much better than plain HTML.

Answer (score 0):

In the form_for you can do something like:

```
<p>
   <%= f.radio_button_tag(:index, "1") %>
   <%= f.label_tag(:index_1, "1") %>
   <%= f.radio_button_tag(:index, "2") %>
   <%= f.label_tag(:index_2, "2") %>
   <%= f.radio_button_tag(:index, "3") %>
   <%= f.label_tag(:index_3, "3") %>
</p>
```